# How to read a value by a dynamic key, form a json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Let assume that I have the following json of config.

```
var config = {
   "type_1" : "Value 1",
   "type_2" : "Value 2",
   "type_3" : "Value 3",
   "type_4" : "Value 4",
}
```

How can I filter the value of type_2, which the key is created dynamically. Some thing like follow,

`var number = 2;
 var value = config.type_+number;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use bracket notation for dynamic keys

In your specific case

```
var value = config[ "type_" + number ];
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you cannot use dot notation, that is why you should use "[bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)" as it is for dynamic keys.

So, you can do it as:

```
var pre_str = "type_";
var number = 2;

var value = config[ pre_str + number ];
```